# Elementary OS 6 not booting - drops into initramfs prompt

Tags: boot, grub, nvidia, apt, plymouth

The issue has occurred after the accepted solution to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675425/regular-update-broke-initramfs-on-elementary-os-6/675476#675476

This is how my screen looks when I power on my laptop

[image: Error on booting]

The prompt is as follows:

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Edit:
How do I try the fsck command? Can you elaborate?
Before turning off my computer I updated intramfs of all the kernels. So none of the kernels is booting. Should I chroot and use  update-initramfs to create new initramfs? I guess initramfs is causing my problem, grub and boot partitions are fine.

Clarification:
After following the accepted solution for my previous question, the problem with apt was solved and I was relieved. I quickly made my move to update all the kernel initramfs. After doing that I checked for updates, there were none. I rebooted to check if everything was fine, but I landed up here.

I suspect the problem is specifically with initramfs, although you can feel free to ask any other information to better understand the problem I am facing

---

I don't know if this is the proper way to respond/keep the thread active but can anybody elaborate what exactly am I supposed to do? Do I need to chroot? If yes then with what Distro? if no then do I need to enter the commands suggested to me in the busybox command line interface? I know something has went wrong with all of my initramfs. What is our objective? Do I update initramfs again or create new? I don't need to mess with grub and boot partition right? I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

This same thread on Unix stack exchange:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675486/elementary-os-6-not-booting-drops-into-initramfs-prompt

I am suspecting that this is an issue about my initramfs, after my apt broke, due to intramfs issue while updating, I fixed it with help of askubuntu forum and once that was fixed I updated intramfs for all my kernels. I guess I need to chroot using elementary os and recreate the initramfs. Can you diagnose the error in the photo. It may be due to Plymouth or nvidia as well.

Thanks